# fonts are Changing alone in a strange way - Windows CE

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-mobile, windows-ce

i have Windows-Mobile program that work with weight Connecting through rs232.

its work excellent, but If the program works in a period of time -

**fonts are Changing alone from big to small font**

I noticed that the problem is in the first part 1 - if i mark this part1

The fonts will not change. (I have no idea why this is happening....)

my code:

```
//PART 1

    port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); 
    port.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recepcion);

     private SerialPort port;
            StringBuilder SB;
            private void Recepcion(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    SB = new StringBuilder(1000);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(122);
                    SB.Append(port.ReadExisting());
                    port.DiscardInBuffer();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Actualizar));
                }
                catch { }
            }


    //PART2
            string MOMO1, MOMO2;
            string[] WI;
            string ALL;
            private void Actualizar(object s, EventArgs e)
            {
                ALL = SB.ToString().Trim();
                WI = ALL.Split(',');
                ALL = WI[2].ToString().Trim();
                MOMO1 = ALL.Replace("+", "").Replace("g", "").Replace("ST", "").Replace("GS", "").Replace("US", "");
                if (MOMO1 != "")
                {
                    MOMO2 = MOMO1;
                }
                lblMSG.Font = new Font("Ariel", 48, FontStyle.Bold);
                lblMSG.Text = MOMO2;
                Check_Weight();
                GC.Collect();  // <-- is it OK ?
            }
```

Can anyone advise me why and how to solve it ?

Comment: what happens in Check_Weight()?

Comment: hi, in Check_Weight()  - is very simple Method - not meaningful

Comment: hi, i update my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code

```
 private SerialPort port;
            StringBuilder SB;
            private void Recepcion(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    SB = new StringBuilder(1000);
                    SB.Append(port.ReadLine());
                    port.DiscardInBuffer();
                    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(Actualizar));
                }
                catch { }
            }
```